# In HttpContent, why ReadFromJsonAsync is an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, network-programming

I'm having a doubt about `HttpContent.ReadFromJsonAsync`  ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0))

In a common way of make a request to an endpoint, this can be done:

```
var response = await Http.GetAsync(path...);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    [do something]
}
else
{
     myObject = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyObject>())!;
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding why when I want to get the object, it is necessary to perform another await operation. In my head, I already got the response in the GetAsync mehotd and what is missing is to deserialize the object only. I understand that the await is not related of converting json to an object  but a network thing.

I tried to find out the reason for this behaviour in the official MS doc, but I couldn't find anything.

Searching on google, I found that even though the content of the response has already been received by the time ReadFromJsonAsync is called, the method still needs to  read the content of the response from the network, and parse the content in order to deserialize it into the specified object type.

But cannot figure why this is necessary neither "where" the content is "waiting to be read", I know that `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync` didn't make a new network request, so what's going on in the back?

Is it temporarily stored in some socket? (or is it nonsense to think so?) Is there a time limit for reading it?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way to understand how something works and why it is made how it made is to look at the source code https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/HttpContentJsonExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP breaks the response up into multiple frames, and makes a clear distinction between the metadata and the response data. The first set of frames contain the status code and headers, and you can quite often decide what to do with the response based on this information alone.

[image: HTTP Framing]

[*Mozilla documentation for HTTP Messages*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages)

In C#, the response object can be returned from a request as soon as all of the header frames have been received.

By default, the `GetAsync` method *will* wait for all the response data to be returned. However there are overloads that allow you to start processing the response as soon as the headers are received.

### Why not just wait for all the data in the first place?

The request content could be massive! Imagine you want to download a 4Gb image, and save it to a file on the local PC. If the HTTP implementation waited for all the data frames to be received, you would end up using at least 4Gb of RAM to buffer the data.

Instead of waiting for the data frames, the content is exposed through a Stream. Data is appended to a buffer, and is read from the buffer by the application on demand. Reading from the stream is an asynchronous operation, because you may be waiting for more frames to be received. The key difference here is that the buffer can have a relatively small size limit. If the response contains more data than can fit into the buffer, you'll have to read from the stream multiple times - which is normal use of the Stream API.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So, when GetAsync is called (and awaited) I get back in the moment the header are received, regardless of whether all the content has arrived. Therefore, I have to go and get the content later. Awesome. Do you know if there are some time limits between the two calls? (I mean, If I have to call "ReadFromJsonAsync" before X time or the data will be destroyed by the SO, may be that time depends on the operating system)

Comment: By default, `GetAsync` will wait for the entire body to arrive and `ReadFromJsonAsync` will be synchronous. This is the normal case. For large responses, you have to opt into the behavior where `GetAsync` completes after the headers are done.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for clarifying, I'll update the answer to reflect this. I assumed it was the other way around

Comment: @Johna if you are streaming the response content, I think the HTTP server dictates how much time you have to consume the response. If it could be dictated by the client, you could overwhelm the server by making lots of requests and not consuming the responses. If you want more detail than that, you'll have to ask a separate question and someone more knowledgeable can answer

Comment: Andrew, Stephen, thanks for your help. I am going to do some research on this last point about the time to read it and if I don't find the info I will make another question

Answer (score 2):

There are for example overloads for `HttpClient.GetAsync` that accept an [*HttpCompletionOption*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption) parameter which allows for *GetAsync* to complete as soon as the response headers have been read while the content of the response has not been completely received.

Therefore, *ReadFromJsonAsync* being async makes sense, as reading the  *HttpResponseMessage.Content* could become an I/O-bound operation including waiting for and receiving the complete content of the response.